# SIM7600 Module: "Connect socket failed" error after several successful HTTP requests

Tags: http, sockets, arduino, at-command, sim7600

I'm using a SIM7600 module with an Arduino for cellular communication. I can successfully make a few HTTP requests using AT commands (AT+HTTPINIT, AT+HTTPPARA, AT+HTTPACTION), but after successful 5 request, I consistently get error code 714 "Connect socket failed" error.

Always work for first 5 requests only then I should restart the module to make it work again .

Here's how I'm using the AT+HTTPPARA command:

```
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://test.com"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
```

I've tried adding delays and monitoring responses, but the issue persists. Has anyone faced a similar problem with the SIM7600 or a similar module? Any advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like it needs some cleanup... client.stop() or AT+HTTPTERM

Comment: It smells like a bug of the device (you know, some dynamic memory that is not correctly freed). I would try @KIIV 's suggestion, as it might happen that forcing term+init sequence again causes some memory release.